# Which of the two is correct? - have been or had been

Tags: grammar

Which of the two is correct? I mean that in the past i had no defence mechanism and i was (verbally) poisoned for some time.

1. I haven't developed a defence mechanism and I have been poisoned for quite some time.
2. I hadn't developed a defence mechanism and I have been poisoned for quite some time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hadn't implies that this is a condition of the past, but that you have since changed the situation. The expected use with *hadn't* would be:

> I hadn't developed a defence mechanism and I had been poisoned for quite some time; however, having developed a resistance, this is no longer much of a concern for me.

Please read the explanations at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84900/present-perfect-hadnt-heard-vs-havent-heard and https://www.englishforums.com/English/HadntOrHavent/hkmmg/post.htm

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence could be rearranged as :
*I have been poisoned for quite some time & I haven't developed a defence mechanism*

The second as :
*I hadn't developed a defence mechanism and so I have been poisoned for quite some time*

or

*I have been poisoned for quite some time because I hadn't developed a defence mechanism*